# Get-ACL and nested groups

Tags: powershell, get, acl

I've seen some code here related to formatting get-acl output and since by the look of it it's not recommended to answer with a question I'm starting a new thread. 
I have a couple of AD groups nested in some local security groups which names include tom and dom. I'd like to expand the locals to show me their member groups. I'm not concerned with users within the groups. Can someone suggest a way of doing this? 
I thought of using get-CimInstance but this seems to be filtering only by giving a specific group name where in my case I'd rather use what comes back from what I've got so far

```
$folders = dir c:\drv -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}
$folders |
foreach-object{  
Get-Acl | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | where {$_.identityreference -match "tom|dom"} |
  Select-Object @{n="object";e={ $folder.fullname }}, 
    @{n="security_principal";e={ $_.identityreference }},
    @{n="type";e={ $_.accesscontroltype }},
    @{n="rights";e={ $_.filesystemrights }}
} | ft -AutoSize
```

so ideally if what comes out as security_principal was split into members of my groups and even better if it displayed only member groups that contain certain wildcards. It'll probably be easier to get the 2 groups and list their members before the rest of the code runs which is fine but again I'm having trouble with getting that to work using get-CimInstance and don't know other way.

Comment: A different approach (based on another thread) allows me to get closer to what I need

Comment: `Set-Location c:\drv
Get-ChildItem * -Recurse
$folders = Get-ChildItem -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}
foreach( $folder in $folders){
  $folder.FullName 
  $acl = Get-Acl $folder.FullName
  $acl | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | where {$_.identityreference -like "*Adm*"} |
  Select-Object @{n="object";e={ $folder.fullname }}, 
     @{n="security_principal";e={ $_.identityreference }},
     @{n="type";e={ $_.accesscontroltype }},
     @{n="rights";e={ $_.filesystemrights.tostring() }} | fl |
     Out-file c:\test.txt -Append    
} `

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting. `code` was supposed to do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

You could view local group membership as follows using Powershell and ADSI.

```
$Server = 'server1'
$LocalGroup = 'Administrators'
$Group= [ADSI]"WinNT://$Server/$LocalGroup,group"
$Members = @($Group.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
Foreach($Member in $Members){
    $Member.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $Member, $null)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Trouble with this is I won't know whether I'm getting a local or a domain group in results. Another that I have to explicitly pass my local group names and they're like 8 long ones of them hence the wildcards tom|dom. Is there a way to use the same wildcards for $LocalGroup? I use
`$group = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Group  -Filter "Name `= 'Administrators'"
`Get-CimAssociatedInstance -InputObject $group -ResultClassName `Win32_Group |
`select -ExpandProperty Caption `

The above takes painfully long but gives me an indication in results whether a group is local o domain.

Comment: Just noticed something puzzling. The get-acl script works fine on my laptop wit PS 2.0 but when run on a different machine with PS4.0 it doesn't display anything even though if run from a single line it works all right. Any idea?

Comment: @yaro137 Perhaps you can Hal Rottenberg's script found [here](http://poshcode.org/544).

Comment: From what I understood Hal's script checks if a particular group can be found as a member of another group. Problem with this approach is I don't know all the names of the nested groups but I know their names contain a specific keyword or two which is why I would need to use wildcards.

Comment: And there is more I'm afraid. I thought the get-acl script works but just noticed it only gives me the last object listed by get-childitem so not good. I'm getting lost in loops...